# Since gravitational waves travel at the speed of light how are Alcubierre warp drives possible?

Tags: general-relativity, faster-than-light, warp-drives

There are clearly some very large technical challenges to overcome before actually making one but most writers seem to think Alcubierre warp drives are possible in principle.

They work by propagating a bubble through spacetime which it's claimed can go faster than light. But isn't that bubble basically a gravitational wave? And they go at the speed of light not faster than it.

Comment: Most writers?  Not knowledgeable ones.  Alcubierre does not take the idea seriously himself, here is a lecture by the man himself https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5q_z8BjiYng

Comment: The drive is a valid GR solution, so it is possible in that sense. Whether that GR solution can be realized in this universe with our physics is what nearly everybody doubts. But the basic question is good: what defines gravitational waves, and why isn't the drive one? A classical field doing something similar would likely be described as a wave solution.

Comment: One can easily make systems that SEEM to propagate faster than light. The difference between phase and group velocity in classical media is such an example. Entanglement is another. The problem is that none of the "ftl" systems actually propagates matter or energy. They all have to be "set up" beforehand and then only do what they were set up to do. They can not be changed dynamically from either end.

Comment: But this does not apply to the movement of the warp drive. It is clear from this that effect and information also go FTL. Inside the bubble is a spaceship, and it carries with it, say, a library and a bomb. Information, matter and physical effects also travel from star A to star B at speed v>c.

Answer (score 3):

> isn't that bubble basically a gravitational wave?

No, the warp bubble is most definitely not a gravitational wave. A gravitational wave is a small perturbation on a background spacetime, usually Minkowski, but sometimes LCDM or Schwarzschild. The background spacetime governs the matter distribution while the gravitational wave is not associated with additional matter. In other words, a gravitational wave is a non trivial curvature in a region without nearby sources just like a EM wave is a non trivial EM field in a region without nearby sources.

In the warp bubble there is a huge concentration of exotic matter. So this is not a source free region. The warp bubble is driven locally by the presence of this exotic matter rather than by propagating gravitational waves.

> most writers seem to think Alcubierre warp drives are possible in principle

I am not at all sure that is true. There is no evidence suggesting the existence of the necessary exotic matter.

Comment: Thanks. I get that the bubble has a lot of differences from a gravitational wave but isn't the basic idea that you're changing the distribution of matter and energy in order to change the spacetime? But as gravitational waves demonstrate this doesn't happen simultaneously. Whatever you're doing with your exotic matter won't have an _instantaneous_ effect on the spacetime so it seems this might limit your speed.

Comment: A gravitational wave may start by a changing distribution of matter and energy but it propagates through vacuum without further changes to the distribution of matter and energy. That is what makes it a wave. The Alcubierre drive requires a continuous change in the distribution of the exotic matter and never propagates through vacuum. It is not a wave.

Answer (score -2):

This is a very valid question!

Clearly, *warp drive and ordinary gravity waves behave radically differently*, governed by different equations of motion. **The biggest difference seems to occur in their speed.** Yet, seen from a distant perspective, they are both deformations of the metric. A deformation of something that moves, that is in motion. So in a way, warp drive can be seen as a special kind of gravitational wave.

- It is an unsatisfactory answer to the question raised that gravitational waves are propagating small perturbations in the background metric; whereas in the case of a warp drive, there is an extensive, strong deformation (bubble) in motion. It is not because there are/can be strong gravitational waves, especially close to their generation.That is, they do not propagate in the flat vacuum spacetime, but in a different spacetime.  Consider, for example, the merging of black holes. By the time they reach the Earth, the effect they produce arrives as small perturbations, of course. But there, in their vicinity, it obviously causes huge and powerful distortions in spacetime and metric.
- For the moment, I can't give a precise answer that would exhaustively explain the substantially different behaviour of the two. But let me note one thing: **the fact that all gravitational waves and perturbations move with c is not proven knowledge.** It is just an exaggerated folklore.
  What is **actually proven is that a special type of gravitational wave travels** with c. The type obtained by linearizing the Einstein equations to look at the wave-like propagation of weak perturbations. That is, we describe weak gravitational waves on a flat spacetime background, with the D'Alembert operator. This is an important type, because by the time the gravitational waves generated in the Universe reach the Earth, they have indeed travelled on a nearly flat spacetime background for many light years and their strength is also weakened to a tiny value. *But let us not confuse this case with all possible cases of gravitational deformation and waves.* There can be gravitational waves that are strong, not small perturbations and there can be gravitational waves that originate and travel on a non-flat spacetime background. **We have no substantive, proven knowledge at all about their propagation speed.** *It may turn out in the future that they can travel in a different way, not at c speed. They may even travel at lower or higher speeds.* To my knowledge, the cutting-edge research that tries to describe them points in many of their results to the fact that the waves of highly curved spacetime *do not propagate exactly at c, but in a range of certain dispersion relations.* Which have a range larger than c. Especially in cases where the gravitational wave is coupled to a field of matter.
  So it is also possible that the issue will be resolved by showing that gravitational waves need not travel with c under all circumstances. Of course, even in this case, the warp drive would still behave eccentrically, since we know *it could move at arbitrarily high velocity* according to the coordinates of departure and arrival.

[Speed of Gravity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.00881.pdf)

Comment: See the difference between phase and group velocity in classical media. I am not sure there is anything to see here that hasn't been seen in much more simple systems before.

Comment: I've supplemented the foregoing with an important source on general gravitational waves, thoroughly examining the issue of speed in it. @FlatterMann

Comment: My point stands. We have PROVEN (theoretically and experimentally) that WAVE-LIKE phenomena exist that exhibit FTL-LIKE propagation velocities. They are simply not waves that propagate from one source to one absorber. And that is the issue, even in general relativity.